# difference between overall code and new code in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, static-analysis, code-analysis, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-ops

I am new to sonarqube and I don't understand how it works.
I have downloaded the latest sonarqube image, I run a simple container and the application starts, everything ok. Community Edition Version 9.9

I have a simple python program and I scan it with the following command:
`sonar-scanner.bat -D"sonar.projectKey=test" -D"sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000" -D"sonar.login=MY_TOKEN" -D"sonar.python.version=3"`

In the first scan the new code tab contains no information and in the overall tab everything is perfect, without any error.

I enter 1 smell code and launch the scan. The new code tab shows 1 smell code and the overall tab shows the same information. I think that everything is correct.

I enter another smell code and launch another scan. The new code tab shows 2 smell codes and the overall tab shows the same information.

If it shows the same information, what is the difference between them?
Shouldn't the second scan show only 1 smell code in new code tab and 2 smell code in overall code tab, why doesn't it happen like that?
Why is the scan not done against the latest version?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can configure in SonarQube your new code period on the admin pages.
It is possible to define from last analysis, for a number of days or from a specific analysis. You need to have a look what is configured on your instance.

For futher defails see in the documentation [New code definitions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/defining-new-code/#new-code-definitions).

Comment: isn't the New code definition setup linked to SonarQube versions starting from v10 ?
for 9.9 link is here: https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/9.9/project-administration/defining-new-code/